# How to uninstall the postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I did try different ways of installing postgresql like version 9.5, version 9.6. I forgot how to install them, by doing this

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

I can't uninstall them. Is there any way to uninstall them by deleting a folder?

Comment: Old but enduring... https://stackoverflow.com/a/2748644/75033

Answer (score 14):

The simplest way to do this is open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql
```

This will **remove the postgresql package**. There may be chances that **additional packages** are also installed so you can search them by typing:

```
dpkg -l | grep postgres
```

and purge all those packages by `sudo apt-get --purge remove {package name}`.

Comment: Thanks! But still i got some left.  Is there a possible way i can delete the postgresql "folder by folder"

Comment: By purging you can delete all the dependencies. Visit postgresql documentation.

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql*`

Answer (score 1):

To completely uninstall PostgreSQL

```bash
sudo apt-get purge postgres.*
```

I just want to add that any packages installed using apt, apt-get or from .deb files for example, can be uninstalled using:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge package_name.*
```

List package and all of its dependencies to check what are being uninstalled:

```bash
dpkg --list | grep package_name.*
```

`.*` after package_name is very important to regex match all possible dependencies associated with a package.

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove Postgres with dependent packages, I used the following commands on my Ubuntu 20.04.

First check the postgres installed version
`dpkg -l | grep postgres`

Then use the following command to remove all dependencies. Use your version number.

```
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-12 postgresql-client-12 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this to purge all postgres-related packages from my machine:

```bsh
# Step 0: stop postgresql services
$ sudo service postgresql stop

# Step 1: double-check to make sure I am not about to accidentally purge something I don't want to purge
$ dpkg-query -W postgres*

# Step 2: purge!
$ sudo dpkg --purge $(dpkg-query -f '${Package} ' -W postgres*)
```